# Can't get TAX working in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to set my TAX rate to 21%. But the front-end calculates 0%.

Does anyone knows what I've forgotten here?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: Result]

note: BTW is the translation of TAX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must also set the **Origin** in **Shipping Settings**:

[image: Origin in Shipping Settings]

Also, check if your products have **VAT Class**: **Taxable Goods** (edit the product, **Prices Tab**):
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But this setting already was set correctly. I must be forgotten something.

Comment: Are your products assigned to the Taxable Goods VAT Class? Did you run a reindex after these settings were made?

Comment: I did reindex after these settings were made. According to the database the products are not assigned to the Taxable Goods VAT Class. Could you give me a clue where I could do that?

Comment: Than you for pointing this out! This attribute doesn't exist. But when I want to go to "Manage Attributes" I get the following error.

http://pastebin.com/N4NMFpE3

Comment: I can't make too much out of that... get a developer that knows what he is doing to fix the website.

Comment: Yes, problem fixed! The attribute "TAX class" wasn't applied for Simple Products. Thank you for all help!!